# Convert a Scheme call-with-current-continuation to Common Lisp?

Tags: scheme

I am converting some Scheme code to Common Lisp. I don't know Scheme. I know a bit of Common Lisp.

Here is the Scheme code:

```
(define (with-process-abortion thunk)
    (call-with-current-continuation
        (lambda (k)
            (fluid-let ((*abort-process* k))
                (thunk)))))
```

I did some reading on the Scheme `call-with-current-continuation` function but, honestly, I have no idea what the above function is doing. My conversion to Common Lisp is very skeletal at this time:

```
(defun with-process-abortion (thunk)
    ;; No idea how to implement
    )
```

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811448/can-call-with-current-continuation-be-implemented-only-with-lambdas-and-closures) says:

> every occurrence of call/cc can be replaced with the following
>   equivalent:
>
> (lambda (f k) (f (lambda (v k0) (k v)) k))
>
> where k is the continuation to be saved, and (lambda (v k0) (k v)) is
>   the escape procedure that restores this continuation (whatever
>   continuation k0 that is active when it is called, is discarded).

Okay, what would `f` correspond to in my situation? What would `k` correspond to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot solve this problem in general because Common Lisp does not have `call/cc` or anything that implements "full continuations." However, you can probably convert this code because it appears that the Scheme implementation is using `call/cc` only for non-local exits, and Common Lisp supports this with `catch` and `throw`, as well as with restarts.

You could try replacing a uses of `(with-process-abortion thunk)` with

```
`(catch 'wpa #,thunk)
```

and replace `(*abort-process*)` with `(throw 'wpa nil)`

Comment: Thank you very much @Doug Currie. I shall give that a try.

Comment: `thunk` needs to be called like `(defun with-process-abortion (thunk) (catch 'wpa (funcall thunk)))`